# Arguing for the statement, "$f$ is bounded on $S$ if $S$ is compact and $f$ is continuous on $S$"

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Is the proof for the theorem "Any compact set in $\mathbb{R}$ is closed and bounded" enough to argue that $f$ is bounded on $S$ if $S$ is compact and $f$ is continuous on $S$?

Comment: Depends on what $S$ is. "Closed and bounded" is equivalent to compactness in $\mathbb{R}$, but not necessarily elsewhere.

Comment: That and the fact that if $f$ is continuous and $S$ is compact then $f(S)$ is compact. So, really you only need that  if a set in $\Bbb{R}$ is compact, then is is bounded (the closedness is not relevant here).

Comment: @EeveeTrainer true, but I don't think that's relevant to OP's question. OP seems to be asking whether their proof of "every continuous function on a compact set is bounded" is correct

Answer (score 0):

You question is not well posed.

If you are asking whether it is true that, given $S$ compact topological space and $f :S \rightarrow X$ continuous with values in the metric space $X$ with the euclidean metric (or any equivalent), then this holds. Indeed, as written in the comments, you can simply show $f(S) \subset X$ is compact and hence you can always find a ball of radius $M$ (say) that contains $f(S)$.

If you are asking whether that specific proof is enough, then I would be more careful. First of all, there are different proof. But even if I kind of see what you mean, some (easy) adjustments may be needed if $X$ is a metric space or $\mathbb{R}$.